# ImportError: cannot import name 'pkg_resources'

Tags: python

I am getting Import error for any package I download
ImportError: cannot import name 'pkg_resources'

I have the Miniconda distribution. Was working fine, somehow i think the setup tools are gone. What ever package I install I am getting the 
ImportError: cannot import name 'pkg_resources'

Please help!

```
(C:\Miniconda3) C:\Users\pkarnati>pip install setuptools
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Miniconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
ImportError: cannot import name 'pkg_resources'
```

Comment: Maybe you installed the package for python instead of python3?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem using pyinstaller. The solution was to edit your-python-path\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\stytle: Go to line 120 and change

```
template = env.**get_template**("html.tpl")
```

to

```
template = env.**from_string**("html.tpl")
```

Then try again.
My problem was I was using background color in pd.Series("backgroud....) and the pyinstaller was not building it, so after the change it works.